# pfs3 error when copying files

Tags: amiga, hard-disk, betterwb

Config: WinUAE 4.2.1, CPU 68020, 24bit, FPU 68882, 8MB FastRam Z2, A1200, CF 4GB Transcend, BetterWB 43, Dopus 4,

When I try to copy folders from PC to CF Partition (2.4GB, pfs3) it goes alright, but then unexpectedly throws bitmap error. I formatted and partitioned the card godzillion times already SFS, FFS, PFS. Same thing over and over again. Always correct MaxTransfer and Dostype were entered.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the WinUAE support forum?

Comment: I've done this sort of thing - creating CF cards with Amiga native filesystems under UAE - with success. However, I've never been successful doing the same on WinUAE. I think UAE accessing raw block devices is better supported on non-Windows platforms. The _most reliable_ and simplest method I've found is firing up MorphOS on an old Mac.

Comment: Have you tried to replace the card?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a card issue alright. I've never had an issue like that with a CF card, SD card or mechanical hard drive when accessing via WinUAE, and it's used all the time by many people so I can't imagine it's a matter of being adequately supported under Windows.

Is the 2.4GB partition located at the start or end of the drive? If it's at the end, try making it a little bit smaller. Sometimes the geometries don't match up, especially with older versions of HDToolbox, and this can make it thing the drive is slightly larger than it actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember receiving a CF card prepped by a friend. I read it with my basic multi-purpose card reader (which works very well for micro SD cards) and coïncidence (or not): the data was destroyed at first access and the card became unreadable.

My friend told me that those all-purpose card readers were low quality for the compact flash format, and recommended a specific CF card reader. Not doing a lot of formats but at least reading and writing CF format properly.

The brand that he recommended is Hama (note: I'm not affiliated with Hama, but it's the only card reader I have successfully tested).

[image]

As you notice in the picture, there aren't 546 formats supported or any USB mug warmer. Just Compact flash and 2 others (that I never used). I've been using that device for a few months (with PFS3 and normal FFS) now and never had any issues, even with cheap CF cards.

I suppose that some other CF-specific card readers are as reliable. Just don't try cheap reader hardware on those cards. Invest in a specific reader.